# (UPDATE)I want to draw circles within circles that get increasingly small by 10 pixels in diameter that are placed around a ring

Tags: java, graphics, processing

So my ultimate goal is to draw 50 circles(with processing.core.PApplet) structured around a ring that transitions colors like a neon sign so that it would look like Psychadelics
The circles have to be random sizes and with a diameter of under 210 pixels the circles have to have 8 bars with each "shells" changing colors in order, and at the center, there must be an empty circle with the same color as the background.
Right now I am trying to break this problem into lots of small problems, and currently, I am struggling to make the spaces between the bars to be equally spaced.
Culprit:
(I found the problem to be the ratio between the bar size and the circle size, due to the undefined range random sizing it made seemingly empty circles)

Here is my next problem, The circles seem to be vibrating instead of remaining static, I want the 50 circles to be static while the colors on each shell change each frame.

**Here is the part where I tell it to draw smaller and smaller circles
This is the "Drawing component"**

```
public Donut(float x, float y , float d) { //constructor
this.x =x;
this.y =y;
    diameter=d;
}
 public void draw(PApplet p) {      
    p.circle(x, y, diameter);
    float bar=(float)(Math.random()*(1-10)-1)+1;
    for(int i =0; i<8; i++) {
    bar+=10;
    p.fill(REDS[i],GREENS[i],BLUES[i]);
    p.circle(x, y, diameter-bar);
    }
}
```

**And here is the part where I tell it to have random sizes and positions(still haven't told it to be placed around a ring yet) //This is the Main Class**

```
 public class Psychadelics extends PApplet{
Donut [] DonutList = new Donut [50];
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PApplet.main("test.Psychadelics");
}
public void settings() {
    size(SCR_W, SCR_H);
}
public void setup() {
for(int i =0; i<DonutList.length;i++) {
    float x = (float)(Math.random()*600);
    float y = (float)(Math.random()*400);
    float diameter = (float)(Math.random()*210);
  DonutList [i]= new Donut(x,y,diameter);
}
```

I have another drawing method inside the main class to tell the Donut class to keep drawing and to keep updating it.

I expect each circle to remain static and to transition colors, each frame but my actual results were the circles each with different colors on each shell vibrating on their specified coordinates

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

The vibration is caused by `float bar=(float)(Math.random()*(1-10)-1)+1;`. Because `bar` is determined inside the draw function, the exact diameter will be slightly different on each frame. Instead, you should create an array of these random floats in the constructor and use `random_diameter[i]` in the draw loop, so the sizes of the inner circles are created random, but remain constant.

The color remaining constant is caused by `p.fill(REDS[i],GREENS[i],BLUES[i]);`. You assign specific colors, based on the index, to a circle that is also based on the index. This is where you should use random. For red, green and blue use `int(Math.random(0,255));`. That way, on each frame, a random color is generated for each circle. If you want more gradual color changes, you'll need to store the color for each circle and add/subtract a small random number. If you want to limit the number of colors, you can use the function you have now, but instead of `i`, use a random number with the size of the array.

I hope you see that, interestingly, the problems/solutions are each others inverse :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!, I have managed to steady the circles and stopped them from vibrating, but then another problem has come up, I cannot seem to use p.noFill(); to make the innermost circle empty and having the background color, when I tell the p.fill to fill the circles with random colors and call p.noFill(); right above my line which tells the method to draw a center circle it seems to ignore that line and fills it either way. Any suggestions?

Comment: The circles are drawn on top of each other. So when you make the last circle `noFill()`, it will show the color of the circle below. Instead, `fill()` the last circle with the background color.